# Transferring access privileges from root to regular user

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I log in to Ubuntu with the username `student`.

There are some directories only the `root` user is allowed to access, for example `/var/lib/mysql`, (I know I can use `sudo` to access it but it is not what I want). If I want to get the access privilege on those directories with the `student` account, can I use the following command:

```
chown student: PATH_TO_ROOT_USER_PRIVILEGED_DIR
```

and after that, can I access that directory by using my own account? Am I right?

- If I am right, then will `root` user lose the access privilege because I changed it to the `student` user?
- If I am wrong, please tell me the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

This directory is restricted to root access for a reason. It is usually a bad idea (and a great security risk) to modify this ownership.

Moreover, instead of modifying the ownership, you could think about modifying the permission on the directory. A user can access a directory if he or she has the right to execute (`+x`) it. If you're unfamiliar with Unix file permissions, I suggest you read a tutorial. (A quick Google search and I came up with [this random tutorial](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm)).

Other things:

- `root` will never loose any privilege. `root` can do anything.
- Only `root` will be able to `chown`.

The right solution

Simple as it is, `sudo` is the way to go. Ubuntu developers know what they're doing. The `sudo` utility is given to make privilege escalation easy and safe. There is absolutely no reason why you would want to change any of this.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm that by using chown, student account then can get the access of the directory which used to be root privileged, and root won't loose the access privilege to that directory, right? I just wanna know the effect of chown, does not mean I will do stupid thing

Comment: The way you worded your question gives us the impression that you're not familiar enough with Unix permissions. It's no coincidence that you got 2 answers linking to outside tutorials. I suggest you look it up. Believe me, read the tutorial :)

Comment: thank you, I will read the tutorial, but can you still answer my question explicitly, if root user do chown a directory which used to be root privilege to the student account, will the student user then can access that directory without using sudo ?

Comment: I already answered: It does not depend (directly) on the owner of the directory, but the access (+x) permission bits. Again, tutorial. You can't guess your way around Unix. At some point, you're going to have to learn it :)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the permissions that are set for the directory, you can do `ls -l` on the `/var/lib/` directory in order to get the permissions for `/var/lib/mysql` .

You can read [here](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html) about the permissions bits in Linux.

But to be specific to your question, if the permission bits are set correctly at the directory (which it should be by default) then the `student` user can access its own directory, and  the `root` user wouldn't lose its privilege to access the directory.
And you should run this command with `sudo` and probably with `-R` in order to change the ownership to all of the child directories.

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* change the ownership of files owned by root (or at least, almost never). Instead, you should use `sudo` to access root directories. `root` always has access to every file on the computer, whether they own it or not. Changing the directory to your own ownership breaks the GNU/Linux security model.